# String from EditText to Float error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert a string to a float.

Basically, I have an edittext that's numerical only, and I'm trying to get the input of it and do some math with it before outputting the result onto another edittext.

Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Declare views
    EditText ptv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceet);
    EditText ttv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taxet);
    EditText totaltv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalet);

    //Declare variables
    float price =  0;
    price = Float.valueOf(ptv.getText().toString());
    float tax = 0.0F;
    tax = Float.valueOf(ttv.getText().toString()) / 100;
    float total = price*tax + price;


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/priceet" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/priceet"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:text="Tax %"
    android:id="@+id/taxtv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/priceet"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/taxet"
    android:layout_below="@+id/taxtv"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/totalet" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:text="Total"
    android:id="@+id/totaltv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/taxet"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/totalet"
    android:layout_below="@+id/totaltv"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cost" />
```

and here is the error I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jimlarck.taxcalculator/com.jimlarck.taxcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

The error points to this line of code:

```
price = Float.valueOf(ptv.getText().toString());
```

How would I fix this? I read somewhere around here that this error is thrown when something isn't initialized properly but everything looks fine on my end. Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `EditText`s after you call `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Declare views
    EditText ptv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceet);
    EditText ttv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taxet);
    EditText totaltv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalet);

    //Declare variables
    float price =  0;
    price = Float.valueOf(ptv.getText().toString());
    float tax = 0.0F;
    tax = Float.valueOf(ttv.getText().toString()) / 100;
    float total = price*tax + price;
}
```

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I didn't notice that, fixed it. Unfortunately though I was getting another error.( Invalid float: "" ), so I realized you can't translate "" into a float so I went into my XML file and set the text for ptv and ttv to 0. Working now, thank you :)

Comment: Done, had to wait 2 minutes